# Linux sort - not sorting properly?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line-interface

I have a big file with 2 columns.  Words and Numbers.
i want to sort by the second column numerically.

I run this command:

> sort -k2 words.txt

and I get this result:

```
Release 99
Some    99
tmc     99
watcher 99
no      990
in      9909
one     992
```

I want this to be sorted numberically.
Why does it have "in    9909" as second last?

tia!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also need the `-n` flag to perform a numeric sort rather than a lexicographic sort.